# Bilingual wordpress : how to switch languages better?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, arabic, qtranslate

I have two websites to be displayed in English and Arabic versions.

After looking around I found that qTranslate plugin does the job very good for a simple solutions.

I used `.htaccess` as the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ar[\/]?$ index.php?lang=ar
RewriteRule ^en[\/]?$ index.php?lang=en 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And at theme `functions.php` the following for detecting language:

```
      function inspectVars($vars) {

      session_start();

      if ($_GET['lang'] == "ar") {
        $_SESSION['custom_lang'] = "ar";
        } elseif ($_GET['lang'] == "en") {
        $_SESSION['custom_lang'] = "en";
        } elseif (!isset($_GET['lang']) && !isset($_SESSION['custom_lang'])) {
        $_SESSION['custom_lang'] = "en";
      }
      $GLOBALS['q_config']['language']= $_SESSION['custom_lang'];
     return $vars;
    }

    add_filter("query_vars", "inspectVars");
```

This session setting I used for switching the RTL/LTR stylesheets. Is there a better way to do so?

Now, the problem I am facing is:

1. How do I use a link which would switch current page, blogs into other language? I used domain/ar and domain/en for switching but that takes to home first.
2. I want to keep the url like `domain.com/ar/someslugsoranything` and `domain.com/en/someslugsoranything`.
3. I have some images, slides at the template which need to be switched with the language change. What is best way? Also there's HTML format texts with them, which also needs to be switched.

Edit:
I have later commented out the following because enabling qTranslate's own language switcher keeps the persistence of language chosen. In fact the whole `inspectVars` functions can be omitted.

```
            $GLOBALS['q_config']['language']= $_SESSION['custom_lang'];
```

Comment: Sidenote; no need to escape the slash. Also you might want to add the QSA flag if you have any urls like `en/?key=value`. So `RewriteRule ^ar/?$ index.php?lang=ar [QSA]`

Comment: For `domain.com/ar/someslugsoranything` use `RewriteRule ^ar(/(.*))?$ index.php?lang=ar&page=$2 [QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved most of the problems.

By commenting out the two lines of `.htaccess` file:

```
#RewriteRule ^ar[\/]?$ index.php?lang=ar
#RewriteRule ^en[\/]?$ index.php?lang=en
```

And many of the problems got resolved with the following post I found just now:

[Displaying content based on language with qTranslate](http://shailan.com/3283/displaying-content-based-on-current-language-using-qtranslate/)
Biggest problem I have now is the mixed HTML texts which need to be switched in Arabic. Within the template I tried qTranslate shortcodes and the `<!--:lang--><!--:-->` tags but they do not work there. Also, writing arabic directly into HTML is not a good idea I guess.

Comment: I also got rid of the following line from the functions.php so I do not store language in session. qTranslate handles it better.

         `$GLOBALS['q_config']['language']= $_SESSION['custom_lang'];`